# Usar engine de template ou trabalhar com PHP puro?

Tags: php

Atualmente aqui na empresa utilizamos a engine de template Smarty, porem é difícil encontrar alguém que saiba trabalhar com a mesma.

Gostaria de saber os prós e os contras de se usar uma engine de template analisando apenas as seguintes situações

- Agilidade de desenvolvimento
- Organização do código
- Dificuldade de manutenção

Creio que avaliando por esses pontos a pergunta se torna mais técnica, não se baseando assim em opiniões

**Realmente tenho que concordar que ainda fica muito baseada em opiniões, porém consegui uma resposta bem satisfatória nos comentários.**

Comment: Rodrigo, você apenas limitou as possíveis respostas mas não deixou de ser baseada em opiniões. Agilidade é algo que não depende da linguagem em si mas sim do conhecimento do programador, quanto mais você conhece a linguagem mais agilidade você terá ao trabalhar com ela, bem como a dificuldade de manutenção, quanto mais se conhece, mas fácil fica de resolver problemas/alterações. O template engine serve tanto para facilitar a manutenção como para organizar o código html, fica mais limpo sem as tags do PHP.

Comment: @Filipe também vejo a utilidade do template engine dessa forma, porem qualquer programador da região que trabalho me diz que o código fica "embaralhado" e que não consegue entender... tivemos vários clientes reclamando que estamos usando uma foma de programação que obriga eles a ficarem presos a nossa empresa em casos de manutenções ou alterações... apesar de que o smarty é muito simples de entender, tem programadores que chegam aqui e levam 30 minutos pra entender como trabalhar com ele...

Comment: @RodrigoBorth o problema dos programadores, é que muitos não tem conhecimento de templates e não vão atrás de aprender, ficam presos em suas zonas de conforto. O que acontece é que eles acham que o mundo tem que se adequar a eles e não eles ao mundo. E os clientes q reclamam, são clientes que não tem conhecimento técnico para falar a respeito (não que se deva esperar que eles tenham, mas é isso). Se fosse eu, pediria então para que eles pedissem uma opnião de um terceiro, que realmente seja especialista ou trabalhe como consultor, pra ver qual prática é melhor :)

Comment: @TafarelChicotti Acho que com essa resposta nem vale a pena tentar adequar a pergunta pra reabri-la :D porém um cliente especifico é um cara que "entende" tudo de programação e tem o programador dele que "sabe tudo" também... e como essa cliente é o que mais da rendimentos para a empresa temos que ficar dando explicações pra não perder o cliente...

Comment: Entendo @RodrigoBorth, só que realmente fica complicado. Mas vocês possuem um manual do sistema e documentação técnica? Porque se tiverem algum documento com tais características, fica mais fácil pra contornar o cliente assim e poder entregar ao cliente algo que ele possa oferecer a outros que forem dar manutenção no código.

Comment: @TafarelChicotti na verdade não temos, primeiro por que não temos tempo pra escrever e segundo por que qualquer programador php que tenha trabalhado pelo menos 4 meses com a linguagem é capaz de entender o código facilmente mesmo sem saber smarty... a prova disso é que um estágiario que começou aqui que nunca tinha programado em php levou 1 semana pra aprender a utilizar as principais funções que usamos no desenvolvimento, o resto foi pegando com o tempo, em um mês ja produzia que nem os mais experientes...

Comment: Eu entendo, eu entendo, mas é que para cliente vale mais uma documentação do que qualquer outra coisa, porque se torna uma prova física

Answer (score 1):

Um framework é um conjunto de boas práticas para a utilização de uma linguagem, com um fim específico. Esse fim varia de acordo com a linguagem. Em PHP, grande parte dos frameworks tem a finalidade de ajudar no desenvolvimento para a web.

Sobre a agilidade de desenvolvimento: PHP possui naturalmente uma agilidade no desenvolvimento. Ao adicionar um framework, o desenvolvedor perde essa agilidade, em um primeiro momento. Isso deve-se ao fato da necessidade de aprendizado sobre a utilização do framework. Porém, após esse período de aprendizado, a produtividade volta aos níveis padrões para a linguagem.

Um framework naturalmente facilita a organização do código. A maiorias das decisões sobre padrões já foi tomada pelos desenvolvedores do framework. Você está utilizando o conhecimento de outras pessoas para agilizar o seu processo de desenvolvimento.

A dificuldade de manutenção vai depender do tamanho da sua aplicação. Para uma aplicação pequena, a utilização de um framework faz pouca diferença. Para uma aplicação grande, um conhecedor do framework terá facilidade em entender a estrutura geral da sua aplicação. Ele ainda terá que aprender as regras de negócio da aplicação. Se um framework não é utilizado, o novo desenvolvedor terá que primeiro se familiarizar com a estrutura que foi criada, depois com as regras de negócio desenvolvidas.

Um framework é uma boa prática de desenvolvimento. Não é algo estritamente necessário, mas é algo que facilita o desenvolvimento de uma aplicação.

É sempre importante escolher um framework que seja bastante utilizado e tenha bom suporte da comunidade, visto que o desenvolvimento de um framework não é uma tarefa trivial.